# Springboot AWS SQS application running on 2 servers

Tags: spring-boot, cluster-computing, amazon-sqs

We are going to work on springboot application which will be deployed on two ECS containers to support the cluster environment. This application will accept the request and drop message into SQS. Another flow in the application should pick the message from queue and process it. As same application will be running on two different servers in cluster environment, I am not sure which server will pick the message from queue. How can I make sure that only one server picks up the message from queue. It could be either server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinary SQS queues do not even guarantee that a message only appears once on the queue - see [AWS Standard SQS Queue docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html)

Using a reasonable value for [visibility timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html#), the time that a message can’t be seen by other consumers, vs the time it takes to consume a message should solve it.

Alternatively you can use an SQS FIFO queue but it’s much slower and can, in my experience, get stuck on a corrupt message.